# Escaping apostrophe in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-2010

I have this simple regex :

```
/^[\w '-]{1,20}$/i
```

However putting `'` inside the set causes me -  Visual studio problems : (color changes , error at the last `}`)

[image]

So I heard that the solution (in order to work peacefully with VS) is to put `\x27` instead of `'` :

`/^[\w \x27-]{1,20}$/i`

Which seems to be fine :

`/^[\w \x27-]{1,20}$/i.test("a-a'a ajaaa")//true`

**Question**  :

Is it the right way of doing it ?

Comment: It's valid `\xhh Matches the character with the code hh (two hexadecimal digits)`. You can try also escaping it `\'`

Comment: @AntoJurkovic `\'` also makes a mess...

Comment: @RoyiNamir what if you saved the regex in a separate var ? [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cKfU5/)

Comment: Have you tried simply `[\w\'\-]` ? I think that would be a more conventional (if not necessarily the 'right') way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `\x27` is a completely legit solution. 
You can compare it completely to the need of typing `\n` as a newline instead of hitting the Enter key and assuming it would recognize it as a character.